# Discord token login using puppeteer

Tags: discord, puppeteer

I was trying to code a discord token login with puppeteer but I cannot access the local storage and enter the value of the token.

What I tried:

```js
                const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

        (async () => {
            const browser = await puppeteer.launch({ headless: false });
            const page = await browser.newPage();
          
            await page.goto('https://discord.com/');
          
            await page.evaluate(() => {
              localStorage.setItem('token', token);
            });
          
            await page.goto('https://discord.com/');
          
        })()
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use variables within the body of `page.evaluate()` you have to explicitly pass them as argument.

```js
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

(async () => {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({ headless: false });
  const page = await browser.newPage();

  await page.goto('https://discord.com/');

  const token = '...'
  await page.evaluate((_token) => {
    localStorage.setItem('token', _token);
      // pass the token as additional argument after the callback function
  },  token);

  await page.goto('https://discord.com/');

})()
```